# How to Change the background color and accent Color of winrt app using xaml Themeresource property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, background-color

I have tried many ways to implement or get the background and accent colors of windows 8.1 to use in Winrt apps and could not get any solution. I would like to know if there is any solution for this other than using uwp or using any third party dlls, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/08/23/Breaking-apart-the-Windows-Phone-81-ComboBox-Style-and-Colors.aspx) will be helpful to you.

Comment: Are you coding to Anniversary Update?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in App.xaml.cs:

```
 String brush="name of the brush you want to override";
 //example : for windows phone the name of the accent brush is PhoneAccentBrush

 (App.Current.Resources[brush] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Green;
```

**Edit :**
You can use this code to change the background theme..

```
App.Current.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"‌​] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
```

use it in the constructor of the page. As for the accent brush there is no theme brush that can be applied directly . For it you can define a page resource and assign it to all UI elements that show accent colour of the system.

Comment: Actually I am dealing with win rt apps and not phone. Also I want to get the background or Accent colors of windows which we can set from Windows->settings->Personalise->Colors. If the color is changed from here it should effect the application.

Comment: Please check the Edit part.!

Answer (score 0):

The value for Accent color in an WinRT app is the following value :

```
SystemAccentColor
```

You can simply use it :

```
<Button Background={ThemeResource SystemAccentColor} />
```

I'm not sure on what you are referencing by Background color? Are you meaning the theme (Light/Dark) used in the app?